# Blazor error on launch of server side of api project

Tags: c#, blazor

Hi I am new to blazor in 2021 so please be kind I created a standard blazor setup with no user accounts as was going to incorporate identity at later stage.

But my server app is producing the following error on launch, I retrieved this from the browser console, im using .net 5 if makes a difference

This is my reproducible repo https://github.com/davidbuckleyni/100daysofblazor
I made my link public sorry about that try now

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for
> property 'AuthenticationStateProvider' on type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.CascadingAuthenticationState'.
> There is no registered service of type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider'.

I am only guessing you will want to see my startup class as follows

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
        services.AddDbContext<PlannerDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddScoped<PlannerService>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP 
    request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

       // app.UseAuthentication();
      //  app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
    }
```

And My Conffig appsettings.json IOm not using azure but the generated code placed these azure values in my config.

```
{
  /*
 The following identity settings need to be configured
 before the project can be successfully executed.
 For more info see https://aka.ms/dotnet-template-ms-identity-platform 

*/
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "qualified.domain.name",
    "TenantId": "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222",
    "ClientId": "11111111-1111-1111-11111111111111111",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=MYSERVERNAME; database=PlannerApp;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

Actually now i just have this error

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not load settings from '_configuration/Planner.Web.Client'
> Error: Could not load settings from '_configuration/Planner.Web.Client'

Comment: The error suggests that `Services.AddAuthentication` isn't registering an `AuthenticationStateProvider` in the Services Container.  Looking at your configuration check everything is correct including the `Domain`.  On my deployment it looks like this `"Domain": "xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",`

Comment: I never set this up was the boiler plate code @MrCakaShaunCurtis and I set it to no authentication as I said am not using azure so why do i need this at all

Comment: I re did my project and selected indiviual accounts seems to have fixed issue

Comment: I assumed you wanted the authentication in and ready to go, otherwise why set up the project that way in the first place?  As you say, you started again with the configuration you want and it's now fine.

Comment: Hi @MrCakaShaunCurtis no I dont I AM wanting no authentication I was adding authenticaiton at a later date using identy